# Account/Login.cshtml view won't use custom layout

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

My solution has two controllers: HomeController and AccountController - both automatically generated by my ASP.NET MVC 4 web application's template.  I also have two separate layouts; the first of which I would like to use for all of my pages in the Views/Home directory, and the second of which I would like to use just for login prompts, etc. - the views located in the Views/Account directory.

Views/Account/Login.cshtml was using the first (the ordinary) shared layout, which looked really terrible. So I made a blank layout for it to use called "_LoginLayout.cshtml":

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
    <link href="~/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
</head>

<body>
    <section class="content-wrapper main-content clear-fix">
        @RenderBody()
        @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
    </section>
</body>
</html>
```

Then I deleted the old Login.cshtml, and re-added it to the Views/Accounts directory, specifying that it must use the _LoginLayout.cshtml file instead of the first.  Stubbornly, it opts to use the prior layout (*_Layout.cshtml*) instead of the one that I just created and specified that it should use (*_LoginLayout.cshtml*).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the problem seemed to be that the view was not generated with

```
@{ 
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_LoginLayout.cshtml";
}
```

on the inside of the view - which solves the problem.